# Issue Appending Jobject to existing Jobject , overriding exisitng JSON without appending

Tags: json, json.net, jsonp

I get JSON response from API and I want to append that API response from each call to the JSON, At initial API response i will be creating the json filelike below. from the second response i would add only few values to the existing json, and I am trying to append values if the json file already existing, if not want to create a new file , below is the sample code , when i am trying to append , its overriding complete json file with the new value without appending it, please suggest

response from API

```
{"properties":{"assignedBy":"put test","policyType":"Custom","mode":"All","description":"Force resource names to begin with given 'prefix' and/or end with given 'suffix'","metadata":{"category":"Naming","createdBy":"33a3582b-5fb6-4aad-8e24-7f751bc0cbe1","createdOn":"2019-12-18T01:03:23.6075759Z","updatedBy":"33a3582b-5fb6-4aad-8e24-7f751bc0cbe1","updatedOn":"2019-12-19T00:47:52.6835216Z"},"parameters":{"ringValue":{"type":"Array","metadata":{"displayName":"put test","description":"The list of tags that can be specified when deploying resources."}}},"policyRule":{"if":{"allOf":[{"field":"type","equals":"Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"},{"anyOf":[{"field":"tags[Ring]","in":"[parameters('ringValue')]"}]}]},"then":{"effect":"audit"}}},"id":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/JamamidaMGTest/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/KVPolicy.json","type":"Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions","name":"KVPolicy.json"}
```

Current Code

```
                var jobject = JObject.Parse(file);

                        if (!blockBlob.Exists())
                        {
                            JObject js = new JObject(
                                new JProperty("properties",
                                new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("displayName", (object)jobject["properties"]["displayName"]),
                                    new JProperty("description", (object)jobject["properties"]["description"]),
                                    new JProperty("policyDefinations",
                                    new JArray(new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("assignedBy", "a")))));


                            modifiedfile = js.ToString();
                            await blockBlob.UploadTextAsync(modifiedfile);
                            Console.WriteLine(file);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        var ms = new MemoryStream();
                        var policyData = blockBlob.DownloadText();

                        var currentJObject = JObject.Parse(policyData);
                        var currentArray = (JArray)currentJObject["properties"]["policyDefinations"];

                        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PolicyJsonEntity>(policyData);

                        currentArray.AddAfterSelf(new JObject(
                               new JArray(new JObject(
                                   new JProperty("assignedBy", "jaya")))));
```

first output :

```
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "put test",
    "description": "Force resource names to begin with given 'prefix' and/or end with given 'suffix'",
    "policyDefinations": [
      {
        "assignedBy": "a"
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

each time after appending it should look like

```
"properties": {
    "displayName": "put test",
    "description": "Force resource names to begin with given 'prefix' and/or end with given 'suffix'",
    "policyDefinations": [
      {
        "assignedBy": "xyz@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "assignedBy": "123@hotmail.com"
      },
      {
        "assignedBy": "sdjk@123.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]?  We don't know the contents of `file` for example, nor what you are currently getting which is not what you expect.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, but are you asking to combine two JSON files by merging their `properties.policyDefinations` arrays?  If so see https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdHFDN

Comment: sorry, added comments for more clarity on my question

Comment: The properties in the API response don't map 1-1 to the properties in your desired JSON.  1) Where should the values to `"displayName"` and `"policyDefinations[].assignedBy"` come from?  The API response contains a property `""properties.assignedBy"` but the value, `"put test"`, seems to be getting mapped to `"displayName"`.

Comment: it was my bad, I mapped it incorrectly , but it should be ,mapped 1:1 , iam sending hard corded values for testing, please refer the code i modified in else condition, it still not working when am appending.